# How to check if all checkboxes are unchecked

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a function to check if all checkboxes are unchecked. I have a similar function for text boxes. As I have not worked with checkboxes much before, I'm not sure how to adapt it except for changing `input[type=text]` to `input[type=checkbox]`.

Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

```
var textinputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]'); 
var empty = [].filter.call( textinputs, function( el ) {
     return !el.value
});

    if (textinputs.length == empty.length) {
        alert("None filled");
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
var textinputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]'); 
var empty = [].filter.call( textinputs, function( el ) {
   return !el.checked
});

if (textinputs.length == empty.length) {
    alert("None filled");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for that. works great. didn't realize there would be such a small difference

Comment: document.querySelectorAll("#divWeeklyDays input[type='checkbox']:checked");

Comment: this also works using jQuery. instead of `document.querySelectorAll`, `$('.get_some_class')` works too

Answer (score 30):

You can simplify a little, given that you're able to use `querySelectorAll()`:

```
var checked = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked');

if (checked.length === 0) {
    // there are no checked checkboxes
    console.log('no checkboxes checked');
} else {
    // there are some checked checkboxes
    console.log(checked.length + ' checkboxes checked');
}
```

[JS Fiddle (with no checkboxes checked)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UYBTL/3/).

[JS Fiddle (with some checkboxes checked)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UYBTL/2/).

Or, if all you want is a Boolean value to indicate whether any checkbox is checked, for use in a function:

```
var isChecked = document.querySelectorAll('input:checked').length === 0 ? false : true;
return isChecked;
```

[Proof-of-concept demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UYBTL/4/).

You could, of course, avoid creating a variable and simply return the result of the ternary; I only used the variable to try and make it clear what, precisely, I was returning/testing-for.

Reference:

- [`:checked` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#checked).

Comment: i didn't know you could do document.querySelectorAll('input:checked') thats very useful, thanks! previously i was using document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][checked]') and it wasn't returning the correct results.

Comment: @user280109: that's because `[checked]` matches the attribute, which isn't updated when the element is unchecked/checked; whereas `:checked` matches the checked property (when it's checked, obviously).

Answer (score 7):

Here, a short and very simple example (Vanilla Javascript):

```
if (document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length === document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').length) {
    console.log('All checkboxes are checked');
} else {
    console.log('Some checkboxes are not checked');
}
```

Here in jQuery syntax:

```
if ($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length === $('input[type="checkbox"]').length) {
    console.log('All checkboxes are checked');
} else {
    console.log('Some checkboxes are not checked');
}
```

Another way to do it, with the [:not() pseudo-selector](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-not-sel-list):

```
if (document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').length) {
    console.log('Some checkbox are not checked');
}
```

Comment: The :not version was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend name spacing with class or id

```
var checked = document.querySelectorAll('input.myClassName:checked');

//or

var checked = document.querySelectorAll('input#myIdName:checked');

if (checked.length === 0) {

    console.log('no checkboxes checked');
} else {

    console.log(checked.length + ' checkboxes checked');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo class input[type="checkbox"]:not(":checked") should work perfectly in jquery:

```
var checkboxes = { id:"hello", value:"value", checked:"false" }

$('.post-text').append('<div id="wrappingcheckboxes"></div>'); for (var i = 0; i<= 10; i ++){ $('#wrappingcheckboxes').append("<input type='checkbox' value='"+checkboxes.value + i + "' id='"+checkboxes.id + i+"'/>");}
$('#wrappingcheckboxes input[type="checkbox"]:not(":checked")')
```

[using this page's console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwVHc.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me,
Give all your checkboxes one class name then:

```
        if ($('.ClassName:checked').length == 0) {
            // do your job
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to iterate over multiple input fields and grab each checked one. I generally use this to add selected elements to their own array

```
let els = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");

els.forEach((v) => {
    if(v.checked) {
        //checked

    }

});
```

If you don't want to iterate over every checkbox, you can iterate over just the selected ones by changing the query selector from `input[type=checkbox]` to `input[type=checkbox]:checked`